# Using $\exp(-At)$ to approximate $(I-A)^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, upper-lower-bounds, matrix-exponential

Suppose $A$ is a $d\times d$ positive definite convergent matrix and $t>1$. How do I upper bound the following in terms of simple statistics of $A$?

$$f_A(t)=\operatorname{Tr}\exp(-At)-\operatorname{Tr}(I-A)^t$$

In particular I'm wondering if $f_A(t)\to 0$ as we consider large "heavy-tailed matrices. Concretely, as $d\to \infty$

$$
\operatorname{Tr}(A_d)\to \infty, \operatorname{Tr}(A_d^2)\to 0\\
\text{implies}\\
f_{A_d}(t)\to 0
$$

Example, plotting $f_A(t)$ for diagonal $A$ with diagonal values $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots,\frac{1}{100}$

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-exp-approximation.nb)

Motivation: this gives the error of using continuous time approximation to model $x_{t+1}=(I-A)x_t$ discrete linear system.

Comment: By diagonalizing $A$, you can show that $f_A(t)=\sum_{\lambda\in\text{spec}(A)} e^{-\lambda t} -(1-\lambda)^t$. The function does not look bounded to me, but I might be mistaken. It is probably better if you replace $(I-A)^t$ with $(I-tA)$, then the function becomes the error function for the first order approximation to the exponential function.

Comment: @Levent $A$ is diagonal without loss of generality, and convergent+psd means diagonal values are in $(0,1)$, which makes it bounded. My hypothesis was that as $d\to \infty$ the following conditions make approximation exact: $\operatorname{Tr}(A)\to \infty$, $\operatorname{Tr}(A^2)\to 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may assume without losing generality, we may assume $A$ is diagonal. Then we have$f_A(t) = \sum_{i=1}^d \{e^{-A_{ii} t} - (1-A_{ii})^t \}$.

We show the following inequality,
$$
-\frac{t(t-1)}{2} \lambda^2 \leq e^{-\lambda t} -(1-\lambda)^t \leq \frac{t^2}{2}\lambda^2.
$$

First note that $1-x \leq e^{-x} \leq 1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2}$ holds for any $x > 0$. Also note that $1 - t\lambda \leq (1-\lambda)^t \leq 1 - t\lambda + \frac{t(t-1)}{2}\lambda^2$ holds for $0<\lambda<1$. Both these inequalities can be verified easily by taking derivatives up to second order. Combining these, we obtain the inequality above.

From the inequality, we conclude

$$
-\frac{t(t-1)}{2} \text{Tr}(A_d^2) \leq f_A(t) \leq \frac{t^2}{2}\text{Tr}(A_d^2)
$$
for sufficiently large $d$.

So the assumption $\text{Tr}(A_d^2)\to 0$ implies your claim.

Comment: BTW, this bound is increasing in $t$ whenever $\operatorname{Tr}(A^2)>1$ but the actual behavior is decreasing in $t$ when eigenvalues decay, I wonder if this bound can be refined to recover decreasing behavior, added example in post

Comment: "$d\to \infty$ with $t$ fixed" and "$t\to \infty$ with $d$ fixed" are different regimes. So they should be treated separately. What I gave is a solution for the "$d\to \infty$ with $t$ fixed". We can also consider another regime namely "both $d$ and $t$ increases to $\infty$ simultaneously". I think it would be better to have separate posts for different regimes so that people here can answer accordingly.

Comment: Posted modified question here -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695082/bounding-error-of-approximating-i-at-with-exp-at-for-large-t