# Bounding error of approximating $(I-A)^t$ with $\exp(-At)$ for large $t$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, upper-lower-bounds, matrix-exponential

Suppose $A$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\in (0,1]$

I'm interested in bounding the following quantity in terms of $t$:
$$f_A(t)=\operatorname{Tr}\exp(-At)-\operatorname{Tr}(I-A)^t$$

Suppose $\operatorname{Tr}(A^2)>1$ and $f_A(t)$ is a decreasing function of $t$, what is a good bound in this regime?

Example, plotting $f_A(t)$ for diagonal $A$ with diagonal values $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots,\frac{1}{100}$

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-exp-approximation.nb)

Motivation: see previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4694646/using-exp-at-to-approximate-i-at/) solved with a bound which is tight for small values of $\operatorname{Tr}(A^2)$

Answer (score 2):

As in the previous question, we may suppose without losing generality that $A$ is diagonal. Let $\lambda_i$ be the eigenvalues of $A$.

We can show that $\lambda_{min} = \min_i \lambda_i$ controls the asymptotic behavior of the error $f_A(t)$ as $t\to \infty$.

For simplicity, let us suppose $\lambda_i > \lambda_{min}$ except for $i=i_0$ such that $\lambda_{i_0} = \lambda_{min}$. Then for any $i \neq i_0$, we have $e^{-\lambda_i}<e^{-\lambda_{min}}(<1)$. Likewise $(0\leq)1-\lambda_i < 1-\lambda_{min}(<1)$. Furthermore, $e^x\geq 1+x$ implies $1-\lambda_{min}<e^{-\lambda_{min}}$. These observation implies that terms that appears in $f_A(t)$ are negligible relative to $e^{-\lambda_{min}t}$. That means the asymptotic behavior of $f_A(t)$ is controlled by $e^{-\lambda_{min}t}$.

Since the sum is a finite sum, we conclude that $f_A(t) = e^{-\lambda_{min}t} + o(e^{-\lambda_{min}t})$.

Just for completion, if there are $k$ $\lambda_i$'s that attain the minimum, then we have $f_A(t) = ke^{-\lambda_{min}t} + o(e^{-\lambda_{min}t})$ instead. So, the asymptotic nature does not change very much.

Comment: An immediate bound from this argument is $2de^{-\lambda_{min}t}$, where $d$ is the size of matrix $A$. When the matrix $A$ is fixed (OP's case), this gives an explicit general upper bound for $f_A(t)$ when $\lambda \in (0, 1]$.

Comment: For the harmonic decay case with values $1,1/2,1/10000$, $0.5 \exp(-t/10000)$ gives almost perfect fit to error after [100 steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSwGy.png) or so

Comment: Yes, as you confirmed numerically, what matters is the smallest eigenvalue $1/10000$.

Comment: The error is bounded above by $\operatorname{Tr}\exp(-tA)$ so  smallest eigenvalue dominates for both eventually, but it's interesting for the error, the "smallest eigenvalue regime" kicks in much earlier, at less than $\sqrt{d}$ steps. The latter needs $>d$ steps for smallest eigenvalue to matter

Comment: But, if you increase the number of steps you should find $0.5 \exp(-t/10000)$ underestimate the error.

Comment: Hm, I ran to 100k and seems [right on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHSws.png)

Comment: My comment above is about the regime "$t\to \infty$ with the size of matrix $d$ fixed". As I noted for the previous post, it is a different story for the regime "$t, d \to \infty$ simultaneously".

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the matrix $A\in \mathbb{M}_{N\times N}$, with a set of eigenvalues $\lambda_n=\frac{c}{n^p}~,~ n=1,..., N$ and will provide asymptotics in the large time limit, taken after the size of the matrix has been taken to infinity. I will estimate

$$f(t,N)=\text{Tr} (e^{-At}-(I-A)^t)~~,~~ N\gg t\gg1$$

This reduces to finding the long time behavior of the sum

$$f(t,\infty)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(e^{-ct/n^p}-\left(1-\frac{c}{n^p}\right)^t\right)$$

With some thought one can conclude that qualitatively, the bulk of the asymptotic behavior of this sum is dependent on the accumulation point of the eigenvalues.

This sum can be approximated by an integral using the Euler-Maclaurin formula. In the $t \to \infty$ limit, it can be shown that all the remainder terms in that formula decay as $e^{-ct}$, so we expect that majority of the contributions to the sum can be efficiently summarized by an asymptotic expansion of the integral

$$I(t)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(e^{-ct/u^p}-\left(1-\frac{c}{u^p}\right)^t\right)du$$

Performing the substitution $x=ctu^{-p}$ we obtain

$$I(t)=\frac{(ct)^{1/p}}{p}\int_{0}^{ct}\frac{e^{-x}-(1-x/t)^t}{x^{1+1/p}}dx$$

We see that the integral converges only for $p\geq 1$ so we restrict to this case. Now, using the Taylor expansion for $-\ln(1-x)=x+x^2/2+...$ we can compute arbitrary terms of the expansion of $(1-x/t)^t$ compared to it's asymptotic limit by expanding the remaining exponential

$$(1-x/t)^t=e^{-x}e^{-x^2/2t-x^3/3t^2+...}=\left(\frac{x^2}{2 t}+ \frac{x^3}{3 t^2} - \frac{(-2 + t) x^4}{8 t^3}+\mathcal{O(x^5)}\right)e^{-x}$$

We can generate as many terms as we would like (no closed formula however). Substituting this expansion into the integral and integrating term by term and taking the upper limit of integration to be infinity we obtain an asymptotic series

$$\frac{I(t)}{c^{1/p}}\sim \frac{  \Gamma(2 - 1/p)}{2pt^{1 - 1/p}}+\frac{(-15 p + 35 p^2 - 10 p^3)  \Gamma(2 - 1/p)}{120 p^4 t^{2 - 1/p}} + \mathcal{O}(t^{-3+1/p})~~, ~~p\geq 1$$

We see clearly that in your special case, $c=n=1$, the integral (and hence the sum) asymptotes to $1/2$ for large enough matrices.

There is no indication for a universal behavior of the difference of  traces in question for infinite matrix sizes, since the integral asymptotics depend explicitly on the behavior of the sequence of eigenvalues. Finally, note that the late time behavior is very different than the one for finite matrices. However, for large matrices with an accumulation point for the eigenvalues, we expect that numerical simulations will give a relatively large region of times where the behavior is described well by the infinite time asymptote, before it actually starts decaying as an exponential $e^{-\lambda_{min}t}$.

**EDIT:** It is clear that since the matrix is finite and the series is slowly converging that the agreement between the $N=\infty$ and the finite matrix curves leaves something to be desired in terms of accuracy. Here is what happens as one increases $N$:

[image]

The black dashed line represents the asymptote to order $t^{-13}$. One can see that $f$ approximates the asymptote well for large $N$ and intermediate times that obey $t/N\lessapprox 1$. However, one can match the finite matrix curves much better for intermediate times by simply performing asymptotic analysis on

$$I_{N}(t)=\int_{1}^{N}\left(e^{-ct/u^p}-\left(1-\frac{c}{u^p}\right)^t\right)du$$

instead, which yields a leading $-t/2N$ correction that needs to be added to the $N=\infty$ asymptote. It is clear that the expansion does not hold for long times anymore, but the agreement in the intermediate time regime is excellent as seen in the graph below:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "asymptotes to 1/2 for large enough matices"? Here's a [simulation](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-exp-approximation.nb) for $A$ with diagonal values $1,1/2,\ldots,1/10000$. For $t\approx 100$ and larger, the error appears very closely approximated by $0.5 \exp(-t/10000)$

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov In the last paragraph I mention how this doesn't work for long times in simulations because of the finiteness of the spectrum... I'm performing a more nuanced analysis right now that matches the intermediate times in simulation very well. Stay tuned!

Comment: In my application $t\in(1,d)$, usually you "don't get to the end of the spectrum" in this regime. What's a bit surprising is that for error I'm seeing smallest eigenvalue start to matter at $t=\sqrt{d}$

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I provided some details. To address your last comment just note that the exponential decay becomes equal to the asymptote when $0.5e^{-t/d}=0.5+1/12t$ which for $d\to\infty$  yields the solution $t=\sqrt{d/6}$.